# Writing to stdin of a child process

Tags: c++, boost, process, boost-asio

I am toying around with the boost process library. But for some reasons, I cannot manage to send something to stdin:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
using namespace boost::process;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    std::future<std::string> outdata;
    std::future<std::string> errdata;

    child c("/usr/bin/cat",
            std_out > outdata,
            std_err > errdata,
            std_in < "hi, there!", ios);

    ios.run();
    std::cout << "stdout: " << outdata.get() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "stderr: " << errdata.get() << std::endl;
}
```

I'd expect this to work essentially like

```
echo "hi, there" | cat
```

But the output is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 std_in < "hi, there!"
```

Opens a file named "hi, there!" and pipes it to child stdin.

Compare: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0343b04d062f3f9c)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
using namespace boost::process;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    std::future<std::string> outdata;
    std::future<std::string> errdata;

    child c("/bin/cat",
            std_out > outdata,
            std_err > errdata,
            std_in < "main.cpp", ios);

    ios.run();
    std::cout << "stdout: " << outdata.get() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "stderr: " << errdata.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Prints its own source code. See also the use of `boost::process::buffer`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc24c730af2c0a6)</kbd>**

> You apparently need to make sure `stdin` is closed afte sending the buffer (?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
using namespace boost::process;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    std::future<std::string> outdata;
    std::future<std::string> errdata;

    async_pipe in(ios);
    child c("/bin/cat",
            std_out > outdata,
            std_err > errdata,
            std_in < in, ios);

    std::string greeting("hi, there!");
    boost::asio::async_write(in, buffer(greeting), [&](boost::system::error_code, size_t) {
                in.close();
            });

    ios.run();
    std::cout << "stdout: '" << outdata.get() << "'\n";
    std::cerr << "stderr: '" << errdata.get() << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
stdout: 'hi, there!'
stderr: ''
```

Comment: Thanks. It is there in the API doc, but I managed to completely misinterpret it ....